# How to call a function while selecting an option in select box

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to call a function while selecting an option in select box.

```html
<select v-on:change="login(this)">
    <option value="github" id="1" selected"> Github</option>
    <option value="bitbucket" id="2" selected"> Bitbucket</option>
</select>
```

I tried the following way in the methods block, but it didn't work properly

```js
login() {
    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].id == "1") {
        console.log("hi");
    } else {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Only 1 option should be `selected`. You can use `@click` event instead, because `@change` event only fire when data change

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to remove the selected" from both html elements and you could consider binding the data option to a watch function that listens to change events, for example:

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    optionPicked: null
  },
  watch: {
    optionPicked: function() {
        console.log(this.optionPicked)
    }
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="optionPicked">
  <option selected disabled>Disabled item</option>
    <option value="github-value" id="1"> Github</option>
    <option value="bitbucket-value" id="2"> Bitbucket</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0f8ugv8/

You could also review vue form binding options at: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html